# List generator in Python with criterias

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How i can set all criterias to one list and search this in string?

```
name = [s for s in files if (("реес")   in s.lower() or ("m&s")   in s.lower()  )and 
                ("элект") not  in s.lower() and
                ("сво") not  in s.lower() and
                ("кхп") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("rar") not  in s.lower() and
                ("пор") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("инф") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("бум") not  in s.lower() and
                ("доп") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("msg") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("сро") not  in s.lower() and 
                ("ank") not  in s.lower()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested condition.

```
[s for s in files if all(val not in s.lower() for val in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'))]
```